# Ignoring a comment line in file

Tags: python

Let's say there is a file that has lines of numbers and comments like:

```
#comments
12 #this is number
2.4 #this is float
```

Read the file and append the digits to the list.
I'm trying to get just the digits, but somehow it appends the #this is number and #this is float.

Comment: Can we see your effort?

Comment: Do you have many lines with a comment only, or is it only the first line?

Comment: +1: The variety of answers shows that there is a need for a consensus on the best approach!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `split`:

```
>>> 'foo #comment'.split('#', 1)[0]
'foo '
>>> 'foo comment'.split('#', 1)[0]
'foo comment'
```

Comment: I think `split` would be better than `rsplit` -- if you use `rsplit`, then `"foo ## comment!"` will wind up with a `#`.

Comment: Also, if you want to grab the comments ever (not sure why you would, but...) without the pound sign, you could use `string.partition()` to make that division for you.

Answer (score 2):

With such a simple case, **you do not have to use the more complex and slower machinery of regular expressions** (`re` module). **`str.split()` is your friend**:

```
output = []

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split('#', 1)  # Maximum 1 split, on comments
        try:
            output.append(float(parts[0]))  # The single, or pre-comment part is added
        except ValueError:  # Beginning is not float-like: happens for "# comment", "    # comment", etc.
            pass  # No number found
```

This automatically handles **all the possible syntaxes for floats** (`1.1e2`, `nan`, `-inf`, `3`, etc.). It works because `float()` is quite powerful: it **handles trailing spaces and newlines** (by ignoring them).

This is also **quite efficient**, because a `try` that does not fail is fast (faster than an explicit test, usually).

This also handles comments found in the middle of the file.  **If you only have a pure comment at the *beginning* of the file**, we can simplify the code and use the fact that each line is guaranteed to have a number:

```
output = []

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    next(f)  # Skips the first, comment line
    for line in f:
        output.append(float(line.split('#', 1)[0]))  # The single or pre-comment part is guaranteed to be a float representation
```

I don't think that there is any explicit approach which is much simpler than this (beyond calculating possibly too many line parts with `split('#')` instead).

That said, an [implicit approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270413/42973) can be considered, like that of abathur, where `eval(line)` replaces the whole `float(…)` part; however, in this case, the code does not show that floats are expected, and as the [Zen of Python](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-zen-of-python) says, "Explicit is better than implicit.", so I do not recommend to use the `eval()` approach, unless it is for a one-shot, quick and dirty script.

Answer (score 0):

While the others have covered the file reading logistics, I just wanted to note another approach: Assuming the file you have follows Python's syntax, you could use the [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function to get the value of the line minus the comments.

```
>>> eval("10 #comment")
10
```

Keep in mind of course that there are security considerations with `eval()` as it executes Python code and arbitrary code execution could be a vulnerability for your program if you have less control over the data file than you do over the script you're executing it with.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but this fails on the "# comment" of the question.

Comment: True enough. I suppose you could filter for lines starting with # first, or, as you suggest, simply skip the first line if the format is that clear.